# Can layouts be chosen by Grails controllers?

Tags: grails, layout

I'm building a CMS as a learning exercise in Grails and would like to give content managers the ability to choose between different HTML page structures (e.g. 2 column, 3 column, etc).

Grails Layouts seem like a logical choice but is it possible for a Grails controller to explicitly name which layout will be used for rendering?  Ideally there would be a `layout` option to the `render` method, per Ruby on Rails but I don't see anything like it.

It seems like it might be possible using the `applyLayout` method by passing the name of the layout but this requires each GSP page to explicitly request layout (annoying overhead per-page) rather than using [Layout by Convention](http://www.grails.org/Views+and+Layouts#Layout%20by%20Convention).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Why not just pass it in the model and have it rendered in the meta tag that determines the layout?

```
<meta name="layout" content="${myValueFromController}"/>
```

I haven't tried it, but I think it'd work.

Comment: This solution would work but I'd like to avoid typing the boilerplate `<html><head>...` wrappers for each view.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a way to do it per-action, but you can specify it at the controller level, e.g.

```
class FooController {

   static layout = 'cms'

   def index = {}
   def foo = { ... }
   def bar = { ... }
}
```

Comment: I saw that one too but I need it per-action, since the layout will be user account specific.

Answer (score 2):

Hey, I think i have a solution for you:
Just use Ted Naleids idea in combination with the afterInterceptor of your controller:

foo.gsp:

```
<meta name="layout" content="${actionLayout}" />
```

FooController.groovy:

```
class FooController {

  def index = { 
    // do awesome stuff
  }

  def afterInterceptor = { model ->
    model.actionLayout = actionName}
  }
}
```

The only thing you have to do now, is naming your layouts like your actions or create some other naming logic.

Comment: Grails does something similar out of the box. If all you want is a layout based on the current controller and action name, you can just not have a meta layout tag and grails will look for views/layouts/${controller}/${action}.gsp.   Your suggestion would work if the desire was to share the same layout for every action of the same name (ex: a list layout).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something, but couldn't this be easily solved with a little  taglib love...?

E.g.

```
<g:if test="${controllerName == 'xyzController'}">
    <meta name="layout" content="xyzLayout"/>
</g:if>
<g:else>
    <meta name="layout" content="abcLayout"/>
</g:else>
```

I use something similar to this for determining which tab should have a "selected" class applied to it within my layouts. This allows me to keep all of my navigational html within the layout while still getting highlighting. A bit different than what you are asking for, but it seems like it could (*possibly?*) still work...